# GifDecoder getFrameCount() always returns 0

Tags: java, android, gif

I'm trying to use GifDecoder to play a gif animation in my android app, but for some reason the GifDecoder getFrameCount() always return 0, which practically means there's only 1 frame and that the gif is not animation but a picture.
I've tried it with several gif files which are all animated, and with all the same outcome. what might be the problem? any suggestions?

here is a small part of the code which is relevant:

```
InputStrem stream = res.openRawResource(R.drawable.smile);
GifDecoder decoder = new GifDecoder();
decoder.read(stream);
int i = decoder.getFrameCount();
```

i always equals 0

even when opening the gif file in the mac i can see all it's frames. So there's noway the problem is with the gif file.

Comment: If you're getting zero frame count it doesn't sound exactly there was one frame available to me. Does this one frame work though?

Comment: that one frame works, it loads the first frame and shows it instead of the whole animation. edited the code in